# Nex.js static file serve with the extension without downloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, static, next.js, serve

I need to serve the `stellar.toml` file in `domain/.well-known/stellar.toml` and the content type needs to be `text/plain`. I tried adding the next config like this and it works only if stellar file is saved without an extension.

I need to serve the content at the `domain/.well-known/stellar.toml` not at the `domain/.well-known/stellar`

```
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/.well-known/stellar",
        headers: [
          {
            key: "Content-Type",
            value: "text/plain",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

Comment: What's the problem here? Simply change your `source` string to `"/.well-known/stellar.toml"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably add the toml extension in the webpack configuration in NextJs. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config

Comment: I must be missing something, because I do not see how this solves the problem. Can you provide an example of how to add an example to the custom webpack config to control the content-type response header?